# View not updating based on the updated value in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am changing the value of `self.display` to `true` if an expression matches a `regex`. I have written this logic in a `$scope.$apply()` block, but I get the `Digest already in progress` error when the `if` block is triggered.

Partial view template -

```
<form ng-controller="termsCtrl as terms">
    <div ng-show="terms.display">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label> Accept </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller -

```
 if (self.regex.test(self.current)) {
     $scope.$apply(function() {
         self.display = true;
     });
 } else {
     self.display = false;
 }
```

The above code works. It displays the `div` within the `form` correctly when `self.display` is true, but I get the `$digest already in progress` error.

I have tried the following so far,

1)

```
$scope.$watch('self.display', function() {
    console.debug(self.display);
})
```

2)

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

3)

```
$timeout(function(){
  self.display = true;
});
```

The above techniques don't produce any errors, but the `div` within the `form` is never displayed.

Comment: How does your $scope look like ? Do you have any values on scope ?

Comment: and why don't you wanna set the `display` value on `$scope` so angular can handle the rest for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use $scope.$apply() when you are executing outside to scope of the angular controller.  For instance, if you were using a JQuery or plain javascript event to trigger a callback, you would use $apply() inside that callback.

Without seeing all your code, it is difficult to say what the issue is, but my initial thought is that you should be using $scope.display instead of "self.display"

Comment: I am using the `controllerAs` syntax as you might have already figured. That's why I don't want to use `$scope`. I am sure there is a better way of achieving this instead of using `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a directive, you need to use the `bindToController`option so that angular watches your values on your controller instance. Otherwise, if you are just using a plain controller and just want to use the `controllerAs` syntax, you have to set the watch manually:

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller('termsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  this.display = true;

  $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
    return this.display;
  }), function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // now we will pickup changes to newVal and oldVal
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal, oldVal);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I am using the `controllerAs` syntax as you might have already figured. That's why I don't want to use `$scope`. If you are not familiar with this concept, here is a great resource - http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/

Comment: I updated my answer, see if that makes sense. Also it would help if you put more relevant parts of your controller here as well.